# Highcharts - change default opacity for series, without using RGBA?

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

Is there a way to set default opacity for (let's say) pie chart to (let's say 0.5), and then when `mouseenter` event occurs, revert it back to solid color?

I know that's possible using `rgba` notation, but I'm looking for alternative solution.

Looking forward for any suggestions.

Comment: It will be possible with new Highcharts release (HC 5). You can find information about this release (and developer preview) here: http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/215-highcharts-5-preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `rgba` notation is out of the question, perhaps you could simply switch the color to a lighter shade to mimic the opacity effect.

For example, if your default color was red (`#ff0000`), you could set the `mouseover` color to a lighter shade of red (`#ffe6e6`). This is, of course, assuming your background is white or another similarly light color.

An HTML color picker, such as this one from W3Schools, can help you select shades for this effect: http://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp

I hope this is helpful!